# Error while executing the coded UI automated test cases using MTM 17

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

**Test Logs:**

> "Queued the TMI run for test run [1594]." TestOutcome 'Warning';
>   Message 'Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0' directly or indirectly referenced
>   by deployment item 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio'
>   specified by the test settings was not found.'."

Several other similar errors.

Not sure why is it showing so.

Comment: Where are you running the tests? A test agent?

Comment: There are [agent, controller for VS 2017 available](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/), try to setup the environment by using test agent, controller 2017 and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to install the appropriate version of the [Agents for Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/11/23/test-controller-test-agent-versions-and-their-usage-in-different-scenarios/) package on the machine where you're trying to run these tests.

The 2017 version should be what you're after if you're using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Versions- TFS 13 , Microsoft visual studio enterprise 17 , Test Agent 13 update 5 , Test Controller 13 update 5 , Microsoft test manager 17